# IntelliJ: Jump between companion object and class

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, is there a keyboard short-cut or navigational short-cut to jump between a Scala companion `object` and a companion `class`?

Comment: I think it should be in the "go to" section", but it isn't in latest EAP scala plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem the answer is *no*, there is not.